# How do I change the stored procedure query into linq to entity?

Tags: sql, linq, stored-procedures

```
SELECT    
    convert(VARCHAR(10), mexpense.order_date,101) AS order_date    
    ,sum(mexpense.price) AS price    
FROM    
(    
   SELECT acc.expensedate AS order_date    
          , sum(acc.expenses) AS price    
   FROM [DWITUserExpenses] acc     
   WHERE acc.userid = @user_id    
         AND year(acc.expensedate) = @curryr    
         AND month(acc.expensedate) = @currmth    
  GROUP BY userid,acc.expensedate    
) mexpense    
GROUP BY mexpense.order_date  
ORDER BY  mexpense.order_date  DESC
```

END

Comment: What have tried/researched?

Comment: var dwitexpenses1 = _Context.DWITUserExpenses.Where(acc =>
                       acc.userid == user_id
                       && acc.expensedate >= Convert.ToDateTime(curryr)
                       && acc.expensedate <= Convert.ToDateTime(currmth)
                       ).
                       ToList();               var grp = dwitexpenses1.GroupBy(x => new {x.userid, x.expensedate})
                    .Select(g => new
                    {   order_date = g.Key.expensedate,
                        price = g.Sum(x => x.expenses),
                     }).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try Linqer from the following site

this converts most of your SQL to LINQ

also helpful if you are using LINQ to Entity

http://www.sqltolinq.com/